# Dump Data Structure of a module

Tags: c, data-structures, gdb, coredump

Is it possible that we can dump all the data structure of a Daemon as a core file (Or any gdb compatible file) for offline analysis/debugging when Daemon is actually not running on a platform(for us Routers). IF so, how can we dump it.

Programming language : C

Answer (score 0):

If you attach gdb to your running process `gdb -p <pid>` then you can use the gdb command `generate-core-file` to write out a standard core file.

Later, when the daemon is stopped, you can debug with `gdb -c <core-file> <daemon-binary>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use gcore command for a process with gdb. It can be used as `gcore <pid>` or `gcore pgrep <appname>` . This will generate coredump of the format `core.pid` which inturn can be read by gdb and debugged. The command `gcore -s` enables to stop the process while gathering the core image and resume when it is done(This is the recommended approach). The advantage with gcore is that you can get the memory image of the process and its states without killing the process.

In case of multiprocess application, the coredumps can get overwritten if saved in the same name, so ensure to use `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core_%p_%e` so that the core dump is traceable with process id and the application(executable).

Here is a good link as far as the daemon cores is concerned - http://www.bonsai.com/wiki/howtos/debugging/daemon_core/